# White screen in my activity_main while others not

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

Hi I am trying to launch an activity which has a navigation drawer and it is simply a `Constraintlayout` with 4 buttons. But it shows a white screen. My other activities appear perfectly. I don't really know why this happened. It happened before when I was trying to build a `gridlayout` but now it's just a plain `constraintlayout` and it still appears the same. If you have any idea, thank you so much!

Here is the XML of a normal layout that works perfectly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Profile"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the XML of the layout that has launching problems :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer)
        val drawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.open, R.string.close)
        drawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle)
        drawerToggle.syncState()
        val navView= findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navigation_view)

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener{
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.nav_profile -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_home -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_schedule -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, ScheduleActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_settings -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_tutorial -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, TutorialActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_about -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, AboutActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_procrastination -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, ProcrastinationActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_premium -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, PremiumActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
            true
        }

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
//    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
//        val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer)
//        when (menuItem.itemId) {
//            R.id.nav_profile -> {
//               Intent(this,ProfileActivity::class.java)
//            }
//        }
//        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
//        return true
//    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer)
        val drawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.open, R.string.close)
        if(drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer)
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the Activity/Fragment please

Answer (score 0):

I had just created by mistake a v21 layout file for my activity. This one didn't had any xml code inside. And as my phone is higher than API 21 therefore i always got a white screen. I just deleted the file and it worked out.